# syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end simple_form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Getting this error with simple_form:

Here is my view page code :

Contact

#### Contact

<%= simple_form_for(@contact) do |f| %>     <%= form.error_notification %>      <%= form.input :name, autofocus: true %>  <%= form.input :email %>      <%= form.input :content, as: :text %>   <%=form.button :submit, 'Submit', class: 'submit' %>    <% end %>

Routes :

> HarrisRobin::Application.routes.draw do   resources :contacts, only:
>   [:new, :create]   root to: 'pages#about'   get '/projects' =>
>   'pages#projects'   get '/about' => 'pages#about'    end

My error :

> SyntaxError at /contacts/new syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER,
>   expecting keyword_end
>
> activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb
>
> ```
>   const_paths = [const_paths].compact unless const_paths.is_a? Array
>   parent_paths = const_paths.collect { |const_path| const_path[/.*(?=::)/] || :Object }
>   result = nil
>   newly_defined_paths = new_constants_in(*parent_paths) do
>     result = Kernel.load path
>   end
>   autoloaded_constants.concat newly_defined_paths unless load_once_path?(path)
>   autoloaded_constants.uniq!
>   log "loading #{path} defined #{newly_defined_paths * ', '}" unless newly_defined_paths.empty?
> ```

What am i doing wrong ? I've been banging my head for hours, don't see the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying `f` as the builder params but using `form` inside your builder:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@contact) do |f| %> 
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :name, autofocus: true %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :content, as: :text %>
  <%=f.button :submit, 'Submit', class: 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```